# ES6 importing extended classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

So I have come across an interesting issue while trying to extend a class to use in another class and then import it to another file.

**'class-test.js':**

```
export default class MyClass {
    constructor () {
        this.date_created = new Date()
        this.posts = new Posts()
    }
}
class Posts extends Array {
    add (val) {
        this.push(val)
    }
}
```

Then when I create a new MyClass instance in another file (and import MyClass from class-test.js), the `myClass.posts` property is only being seen as an Array and so doesn't have the extended function `add()`

I think the problem is that the Posts class is not being moved with the MyClass class; but without casting I have no idea how to tell it to use that class.

Where I'm particularly frustrated is it works fine if all in one file:

```js
class MyClass {
 constructor () {
  this.date_created = new Date()
  this.posts = new Posts()
 }
}

class Posts extends Array {
 add (val) {
  this.push(val)
 }
}

var x = new MyClass('as', 'asd')
x.posts.add('asdf')
console.log(x.posts)
x.posts.add('qwer')
x.posts.add('zxcv')
console.log(x.posts)
```

Comment: Are you using Babel? I don't believe it supports extending built-ins by default when transpiling, but there are plugins like [`babel-plugin-transform-builtin-classes`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-classes) that allow it to be done by forcing a non-strict transpilation for extension of native classes like `Array`.

Comment: I am using Babel, so that's the issue. Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I can't get that plugin to work, but now I know the issue I may go another route to maintain compatibility while classes are still "new".

Comment: @theservant Really, you should not have a `Posts` class the extends `Array`. Just use a normal array.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to export, and import both classes ?

*'class-def.js':*

```
class MyClass {
    constructor () {
        this.date_created = new Date()
        this.posts = new Posts()
    }
}

class Posts extends Array {
    add (val) {
        this.push(val)
    }
}

export { MyClass, Posts };
```

*'class-test.js':*

```
import { MyClass, Posts } from 'class-def.js';
var x = new MyClass('as', 'asd')
x.posts.add('asdf')
console.log(x.posts)
x.posts.add('qwer')
x.posts.add('zxcv')
console.log(x.posts)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue, as @patrick-roberts pointed, out is Bable does not support extending built-in classes without another work-around package:
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-classes/
For now I just used a different method to achieve what I wanted as I don't need another package and am not ready to jettison Babel.